# Make the Current Tab Full Screen in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to make the current tab in IntelliJ go full screen (and vice versa - back to split tabs)?

For example, if I have 3 tabs split open and I want the middle tab to temporarily consume my entire screen - is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done in one of the latest releases:

https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2021/02/intellij-idea-2021-1-eap-2/

Answer (score 2):

Not possible at the moment, please vote:

- [IDEA-82829](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-82829) Maximize editor window should hide other editor in split view

Comment: Thanks. This ticket is 11 years old, is it being seriously considered?